# Vue component - tag table works bad, is under rows

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

im learnign VUE JS and I dont understand this behavior (strange for me).

I want to get list of people in table via Vue component.
Html tag table is under the list.

Documentation says: Every compoment must have one single root, ok I can wrap each tr with tbody but it doesnt solve this problem.

How to solve it?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="app">

            <table>
    <row
      v-for="people in peoples"
      v-bind:people="people"
      v-bind:key="people.id">
    </row>
   </table>
   
        </div>
        
        <script>

   Vue.component('c-tr', {

    template: '<tr></tr>'
   });

   Vue.component('row', {
    props: ['people'],
    template: '<tr><td>{{ people.name }}</td></tr>'
   });

   var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
    peoples: [
     { id: 20, name: 'Roman' },
     { id: 30, name: 'Vasek' },
     { id: 40, name: 'Ondra' }
    ]
    }
   })

 
  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use a template directly in an HTML file you'll run into the parsing caveats that come with that. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats. In particular you'll need to use the `is` attribute to replace `<row>` with `<tr is="row">`. You won't have this problem if you define your templates as strings or in `.vue` files.

Comment: Great!  Thank you :-)